# Dropping duplicates based on other column values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I would like to drop duplicates in column A based on values in other columns.  I have searched tirelessly and cant find a solution like this.

example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family1 | nan | nan |
| Family1 | nan | 1234 |
| Family1 | 1245 | nan |
| Family1 | 3456 | 78787 |
| Family2 | nan | nan |
| Family3 | nan | nan |

Basically i want to drop a duplicate ONLY IF the rest of the columns are both nan. otherwise, the duplicate can stay.

desired output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family1 | nan | 1234 |
| Family1 | 1245 | nan |
| Family1 | 3456 | 78787 |
| Family2 | nan | nan |
| Family3 | nan | nan |

Family2 and Family3 remain in the df because they dont have duplicates, even though both columns are nan

Comment: can you include the code that creates of a dataframe of the source table?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Family1','Family1','Family1','Family1','Family2','Family3'],'B':[np.nan,np.nan,1245,3456,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[1234,np.nan,78787,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not very clear. I suspect you want to drop any duplicates in column A if both columns B and C are NaN. If so, please try;

```
df[~(df.A.duplicated(keep=False)&(df.B.isna()&df.C.isna()))]
```

Answer (score 3):

try a double boolean, this returns true for all duplicates & true for any column after ['A'] that are all nulls. If both conditions are met we will exclude this using the `~` operator which inverts a boolean.

```
df[~(df.duplicated(subset=['A'],keep=False) & df.iloc[:,1:].isna().all(1))]

          A     B        C
1  Family1    NaN     1234
2  Family1   1245      NaN
3  Family1   3456    78787
4  Family2    NaN      NaN
5  Family3    NaN      NaN
```